# Setting up MySQL on a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I've been moving my site from GoDaddy to Google Cloud and I'm very close to being able to launch. The only missing piece is setting up the database.

I've already installed MySQL on the server and when I run `sudo service mysql status`, it says that `mariadb.service` is active (running) and "Taking your SQL requests now..."

I also added the VM instance's IP address to the SQL instance's Connections.

However, when I try to connect on the live site, I get a php error that reads:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysql' not found in db.php:3

Am I missing a setup step? I followed all of Google's tutorials and help files about this and don't understand what I'm missing.

I installed the libraries with these commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

I'm trying to connect with this string in my php code:

`$dbcon=@new mysql('[SQL instance IP address]','[DB username]','[DB password]','[DB name]');`

Comment: Which PHP MySQL library are you using? This error means that it cannot find the class `mysql` which means that you have not set up / installed the libraries correctly. Edit your question with details and include the PHP module that generates this error.

Comment: I installed the libraries with these commands:

```sudo apt-get update```

```sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php```

```sudo apt-get install mysql-server```

```sudo apt-get install mysql-client```

Comment: Delete the comment and edit your question with changes/improvements. Where is your source code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I see. I updated my question. I hope it's more understandable / comprehensive now.

Comment: Try using `$dbcon = new mysqli( ....)`. Replace the function parameters with real values. The ones in your question will not work. Typically if your code is running inside the same machine as MySQL, then use `localhost` for the IP address. Check your `php.ini` for the line `extension=mysqli.so` to enable this code. If this is confusing, find a good tutorial on the web and practice with it.

Comment: Thanks. I do have real values but just replaced them with [things] above. I don't have ```extension=mysqli.so``` in either the cli or apache2 php.ini files. Should I add ```extension=mysqli.so``` to these files?

Comment: If you want to use the PHP MySQL APIs, you need to enable the extensions. You might have more than one php.ini file on your system. One installed by PHP and another for Apache. Enable in all php.ini files.

Comment: Hi again. I just realised that I had to install mysqlnd with

```sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqlnd```

Finally, the fatal error is fixed! Now, on to actually getting it to work which should be a breeze now.

Comment: That was my question regarding which library you are using. Remember, do not use the classes from `mysql` which are no longer recommended. Use `mysqli`. MySQL recommends using the MySQL native driver for PHP (mysqlnd) together with ext/mysqli or PDO_MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: Thanks! I set it all up 100% now. Feel free to leave an answer here and I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, do three things:

1) Install the PHP MySQL Extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqlnd
```

2) Make sure that the extension is enabled in your `php.ini` file. There will be one for the PHP interpreter and another one for the Apache web server.

3) Change your code to not use the `mysql` class and use `mysqli` instead:

```
$dbcon = new mysqli('localhost', $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
```